# Swagger Code Generator Is Failing With StackOverflowError

Tags: swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate some model objects to use in my Java/Spring Boot application using the following JSON file:

https://github.com/tmforum-apis/TMF622_ProductOrder/blob/master/Product_Ordering_Management.regular.swagger.json

I've included the following in my POM.xml:

```
<version.swagger.codegen>3.0.10</version.swagger.codegen>
<version.swagger.annotations>2.0.8</version.swagger.annotations>

<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.swagger.codegen}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/swagger/tmf622/product_ordering_management.json</inputSpec>
                <modelPackage>tmf622.v1.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>tmf622.v1.api</apiPackage>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>                           
                <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
                <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>      
                <language>spring</language>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>                           
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${version.swagger.annotations}</version>
        </dependency>                  
    </dependencies>               
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and when i build the application i get the following StackOverflowError:

```
constituent[47]: file:/C:/Software/apache-maven-3.6.1/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.3.2.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.debug(SimpleLogger.java:438)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:165)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:194)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:194)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:247)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.examples.ExampleGenerator.resolveSchemaToExample(ExampleGenerator.java:240)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9546) is caused by recursive schemas in the API definition. It was fixed in Swagger Codegen 3.0.11.

Comment: Where is the latest SNAPSHOT available, i can only see version 3.0.10 here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

Comment: Snapshots are on Sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/codegen/v3/. You'll need to add `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/` to the `<pluginRepositories>` in your pom.xml or in settings.

Comment: My Model Objects that get built in my target folder fail to compile with this error: Ref.java:[29,18] illegal start of type which references the follosing: private String @ReferredType = null;  Am i missing something?

Comment: This is an unrelated issue. The API definition contains some property that start with `@` but Java identifiers cannot start with `@`. Codegen should probably escape or modify such property names to make them valid identifiers. Please open a ticket at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: Since your API definition is `swagger: '2.0'` (and not `openapi: 3.0.0`) you can use Codegen v. 2.4.7 instead of 3.x; it has `<groupId>io.swagger</groupid>`. Version 2 generates the property as `private String referredType` instead of `private String @ReferredType`.